# Combining Facebook login with Spring Security

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-security

I have implemented Facebook login at client side and separately implemented login via Spring Security. Now I want to combine them by using the Facebook login as username and password to Spring Security. The Facebook login looks mainly like this:

```
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
       if (response.status === 'connected') {
       testAPI();
     }
  }

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {   
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'my app id',
    cookie     : true,  
  });




  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
  };

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
      document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = response.username;
    });
  }
```

And the Spring Security classes I have taken from an example I found.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "rockandroll";

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/index.html")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/chat.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/js/**", "/lib/**", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/index.html", "/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/websocket").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
        }

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD.equals(token.getCredentials()) ? 
                                                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN") : null;

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getName(), token.getCredentials(), authorities);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the second one:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebApplicationInitializer extends             AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages
            .simpMessageDestMatchers("/topic/test.login", "/topic/test.logout", "/topic/test.message").denyAll()
            .anyMessage().authenticated();
}


}
```

I would like to pass the userid etc from Facebook to Spring Security and let Spring Security authorize the user. 
I have tried to find information about it and found some examples but they does not fit my configuration etc. If somebody could indicate where I should start read or have any code example I can look at it would be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of combining SPRING Security with the way that Facebook suggest how ot integrated Facebook loggin to a web page I decided to use SPRING Social together with SPRING Security.

This blogg gives an example of how I did it:

http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/09/02/adding-social-login-to-a-website-using-spring-social/